# DataGridView not selecting last row on load

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` as part of a form that, when all of its rows are populated, should select the last row by default.

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Reload();
}

private void Reload()
{
    // add/populate the rows here

    if(dgv.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        dgv.Rows[dgv.Rows.Count - 1].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

I have the `SelectionMode` set to `FullRowSelect` and `MultiSelect` is `false`.

Anyone know why this isn't working? The first row is always still selected when the form pops up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue stems from the [Order of Events in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d(v=vs.110).aspx) when loading a `Form`. If you call `Reload()` in the constructor of the `Form` the forms controls haven't actually had a chance to load yet. Instances of them exist, but not the rendered objects.

Instead you should override one of the other form load events such as `OnLoad` and call `Reload()` from there. Remove the call to `Reload()` from your constructor.

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    Reload();
}

private void Reload()
{
    // add/populate the rows here
    if(dgv.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        dgv.Rows[dgv.Rows.Count - 1].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Using this method will ensure that your controls have finished loading before you start manipulating them.